# Leaflet control dialog draggable on touch screens

Tags: javascript, leaflet, touch, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have issues with dragging Leaflet dialogs on touch devices.

I am using Leaflet 1.0.3 (http://leafletjs.com/) and Leaflet.Dialog plugin (https://github.com/NBTSolutions/Leaflet.Dialog) to display some information on top of the map. It works perfectly fine with mouse events. However, it completely fails on touch screens.

I suspected that Leaflet's map event listeners on touch devices prohibited touch events on overlay elements so I've tried setting dragging and tap to false in map options, but neither worked. I've also added jquery-ui draggable functionality on the dialogs that made the entire dialog boxes draggable on non-touch screen devices; still no luck with touch events though. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 5/*,
    tap: false,
    dragging: false*/});

var dialog = L.control.dialog(options)
    .setContent("test")
    .addTo(map);

$('.leaflet-control-dialog').draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question I managed to get it working using the Touch Punch jQuery-UI plugin:
https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/

I'd still be interested to know whether this can be done with native Leaflet functions.